# Laravel - deleting a guest user after the user logs out

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 5.4 and I want to delete a guest user from the users table after he logs out. So I created a `LogoutEventListener` class (followed instructions from documentation) and I am able to successfully delete the user in the `handle(Logout $event)` function.

However I am unable to determine if Laravel's own `logout()` function in `AuthenticatesUsers` trait is called either before or after the above `handle` function. A`dd(...)` statement at the beginning of this function never seems to be called. So I am afraid of any unforeseen sideeffects.

So, is it safe to delete the user in the `LogoutEventListener::handle()` function?

Answer (score 0):

Those are events for laravel 5.2 +

```
 $events->listen(
            'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout',
            'App\Listeners\UserEventSubscriber@onUserLogout'
        );
```